# SpringFramework set selected FilePath to a "path attribute" of form

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

When a file is selected it must set the fileName with path to a textField with path="inputFileName". I tried to below code which is not working as setFileName is not called either onClick nor onSelect.

Any pointers how this can be done will be great help to me.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="f" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%! 
    public void setFileName(){
        System.out.println("In SetFile Name for InputFile");
    }
%>
<html>

<body>
File Convertor
<PRE>
<f:form method="PUT" commandName="file2" >
Input File  <f:input path="inputFileName"/><input type="file" name="ChooseMyFile" value="A" onclick="setFileName()" onselect="setFileName()"/>

Output File <f:input path="outputFileName"/>
</f:form>
</PRE> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JSPs are executed at server-side. JavaScript is executed at client-side, in the browser. You're trying to execute Java code from a JavaScript onclick handler. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thanks , for rectifying the mistake. I am trying to set a file path selected from the local computer to <f:input path="inputFileName"> using a javascript.